# Why I cannot use Gmail configuration for Zimbra mail?

Tags: java, gmail-api, email-client, zimbra

I have gmail configuration script for send email using Gmail mail service, and these codes can send email Correctly:

```
public static void sendEmail() throws AddressException, MessagingException {
    String emailBody = "This is body of message xxx";

    mailServerProperties = System.getProperties();
    mailServerProperties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    mailServerProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    mailServerProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

    getMailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(mailServerProperties, null);
    generateMailMessage = new MimeMessage(getMailSession);
    generateMailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, new InternetAddress(receiveremail@gmail.com));
    generateMailMessage.setSubject("This is subject xxx");

    generateMailMessage.setContent(emailBody, "text/html");
    Transport transport = getMailSession.getTransport("smtp");
    transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", "my-email@gmail.com", "mypasswordxxx");
    transport.sendMessage(generateMailMessage, generateMailMessage.getAllRecipients());
    transport.close();
}
```

Then I want to use Zimbra mail service with my own mail domain (findtaxi.com). 
I want send email using my email domain (justin@findtaxi.com), it use Zimbra service. I follow this [configuration](https://community.alfresco.com/docs/DOC-4799-outbound-e-mail-configuration), I change some values :

```
 mailServerProperties.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
 transport.connect("zimbra.findtaxi.com", "justin@findtaxi.com", "thispassword");
```

But cannot send the message.

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: zimbra.findtaxi.com, port: 25; nested exception is: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

Is it possible to send email with Zimbra on javamail?

Comment: Do you have all your configuration ok? Check the config, it seems like you cant reach the SMTP server.

Comment: Yes, with Gmail configuration I could send an email. But when I changed to Zimbra account, it cannot send the email